# How to get active session user SID?

Tags: vbscript, cmd

How to get active session user SID? (it is current user session)

I can do this using CMD command:

```batch
for /f "tokens=2-4" %a in ('qwinsta') do @if "%c"=="Active" wmic useraccount where name='%a' get sid
```

Maybe someone can tell me how to do same with VBScript?

By "current user" I mean "the account that started the script before UAC made me enter Admin credentials".

Comment: Edit your question on what `'qwinsta'` contains.

Comment: [qwinsta](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731503(v=ws.11).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Give a try for this vbscript :

```
Option Explicit
Dim strUser
strUser = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserName
Wscript.echo "The SID of this username " & strUser & " is :" &_
vbcr & GetSIDFromUser(strUser)
'******************************************************************
Function GetSIDFromUser(UserName)
  Dim DomainName, Result, WMIUser
  If InStr(UserName, "\") > 0 Then
    DomainName = Mid(UserName, 1, InStr(UserName, "\") - 1)
    UserName = Mid(UserName, InStr(UserName, "\") + 1)
  Else
    DomainName = CreateObject("WScript.Network").UserDomain
  End If
  On Error Resume Next
  Set WMIUser = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationlevel=impersonate}!" _
    & "/root/cimv2:Win32_UserAccount.Domain='" & DomainName & "'" _
    & ",Name='" & UserName & "'")
  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Result = WMIUser.SID
  Else
    Result = ""
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0
  GetSIDFromUser = Result
End Function
'******************************************************************
```

***NB :***  I got it from this link **[How to find out logged on users SID with VBScript?](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/c6adc2cb-7d24-4b6e-a0e4-e60da3813158/how-to-find-out-logged-on-users-sid-with-vbscript?forum=ITCG)**

Comment: Thank you for response, Ths script works, almost, problem is when I run it as a administrator, It returns me `admin SID` I would like to get current user from which I call this script, despite `run as administrator`

Comment: I know, that is why I asking for help, for example my `cmd` command does the trick.

Comment: @Bublik You can find out the SID of any user with this function, just call it with a different `UserName` parameter

Comment: yes, but I need to get current user name, despite `run as administrator`

Comment: Define "current user".

Comment: how? i can run this script from any user on machine?

Comment: I know that by "current user" you mean "The account that started the script before UAC made me enter Admin credentials". But from the perspective of the script it's a different matter. It does not know that it runs as Admin because of UAC, and it does not know that it was one of the other users logged into this PC that caused this to happen. All it knows is that it runs as Admin. If you want context information, you must provide it explicitly - for example by calling the script with a command line parameter that contains the username you are interested in.

Comment: Check the [owner](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390460%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the `explorer.exe` process.

Answer (score 0):

***Get SID for current logged in domain user***

Run the command `whoami /user` from command line to get the `SID` for the logged in user.

Example:

> ```
> c:\>whoami /user
> USER INFORMATION
> ----------------
> User Name      SID
> ============== ==============================================
> mydomain\wincmd S-1-5-21-7375663-6890924511-1272660413-2944159
> c:\>
> ```

And you can do something like that with a batch file :

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2 delims=," %%a in ('Whoami /user /FO CSV') do ( 
    set "UserName=%%a"
    set "SID=%%b"
    echo The username logged is : !Username!
    echo.
    echo And its SID = !SID!
)
pause
exit
```